# Sails.js add attribute from another table to a model

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to pull an extra attribute for a model from a different table.
I have been trying with associations but it seems wrong to create an extra model and associate that to my original model.

This is my model Company.js

```
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    autoPK: false, 

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        url: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        summary: {
            type: 'text'
        }
    }
};
```

I have another table in MySQL with two columns, crunchbase_url and company_id, I would like to pull the crunchbase_url into the Company model, what would be the best way to do it without migrating the DB (not an option unfortunately).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out that the documentation is fine and all works like a charm by simply creating another model and using one to many association with joined with via.

However, there is a bug that threw me off:

[When defaultLimit is set to -1, the find action return an empty list if there are associations.](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2352)